# Margins on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, jupyter, margins

I created a data frame and set Margins to True when I created a pivot table however after using the `to_records()` statement, the Margin created as the last row with 'ALL' has now been identified as a record within the dataframe which I do not want, having 'ALL' as the ID of that row instead of still being a margin. Is there a way to delete the last row or not allow the Margins to be used as records after converting from pivot to df?

Answer (score 0):

to delete the last row, you can either do

```
df = df.head(len(df) - 1)
```

or, if it has a unique index `index_to_remove`

```
df = df.drop('index_to_remove', axis=0)
```

a third option is:

```
df = df.iloc[:-1]
```

And plenty other methods exist